# Sort DataFrame conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I'm not sure of the best way to title this question.

As an example, I have the following DataFrame (here sorted by `Title`):

```
         AlbumArtist              Album  Track                       Title  Year
0          BABYMETAL       METAL GALAXY      2                 DA DA DANCE  2019
1  Bandai..Sora Ltd.  Super Smash Bros.      3              Death Mountain  2018
2          BABYMETAL       METAL GALAXY      1                FUTURE METAL  2019
3          BABYMETAL   METAL RESISTANCE      2                      Karate  2016
4          BABYMETAL   METAL RESISTANCE      1          Road of Resistance  2016
5  Bandai..Sora Ltd.  Super Smash Bros.      2                Temple Theme  2001
6  Bandai..Sora Ltd.  Super Smash Bros.      1  The Legend of Zelda Medley  2015
```

I want to sort it by `AlbumArtist`, then by `Album` *grouped by `Year`*, then by `Track`
So, to be clear, between two rows, `Year` takes priority ONLY when `Album` is the same

The output should be

```
         AlbumArtist              Album  Track                       Title  Year
4          BABYMETAL   METAL RESISTANCE      1          Road of Resistance  2016
3          BABYMETAL   METAL RESISTANCE      2                      Karate  2016
2          BABYMETAL       METAL GALAXY      1                FUTURE METAL  2019
0          BABYMETAL       METAL GALAXY      2                 DA DA DANCE  2019
6  Bandai..Sora Ltd.  Super Smash Bros.      1  The Legend of Zelda Medley  2015
5  Bandai..Sora Ltd.  Super Smash Bros.      2                Temple Theme  2001
1  Bandai..Sora Ltd.  Super Smash Bros.      3              Death Mountain  2018
```

I have tried using sort keys, `MultiIndex` `groupby()`, `rank()`... but I can't quite work out how to do this.

I can approximate the functionality I want by using using a class with `__lt__` and sort functions (below), but I suspect this will be less efficient than `pandas` on larger amounts of data.

```py
class Song():
    def __init__(self, albumArtist, album, track, title, year):
        self.data = {
            "albumArtist": albumArtist,
            "album": album,
            "track": track,
            "title": title,
            "year": year,
        }

    def __lt__(self, other):
        for field in sortOrder:
            if self.data[field[0]] != other.data[field[0]]:
                if len(field) > 1: # Want secondary sort
                    return self.data[field[1]] < (other.data[field[1]])
                else: # Regular sort
                    return self.data[field[0]] < (other.data[field[0]])

    def __str__(self):
        return str(list(self.data.values()))


sortOrder = [
    ("albumArtist",),
    ("album", "year"),
    ("track",),
]
rows = [
    Song("BABYMETAL", "METAL GALAXY", 2, "DA DA DANCE", 2019),
    Song("Bandai..Sora Ltd.", "Super Smash Bros.", 3, "Death Mountain", 2018),
    Song("BABYMETAL", "METAL GALAXY", 1, "FUTURE METAL", 2019),
    Song("BABYMETAL", "METAL RESISTANCE", 2, "Karate", 2016),
    Song("BABYMETAL", "METAL RESISTANCE", 1, "Road of Resistance", 2016),
    Song("Bandai..Sora Ltd.", "Super Smash Bros.", 2, "Temple Theme", 2001),
    Song("Bandai..Sora Ltd.", "Super Smash Bros.", 1, "The Legend of Zelda Medley", 2015),
]

for item in sorted(rows):
    print(item)
```

What is the `pandas` way to do this?